# How to add millisecond in Date Modified in windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, microsoft-file-explorer

The date format of `Date modified` in the File Explorer of my computer is `HH:mm`. How can I add seconds and milliseconds in the datetime? Now the files are ordered by `Date modified` desend, they have the same `Date modified`, how they are ordered by the windows system?

[image]

Comment: Windows does not do a straight string comparison, I assume it compares the full time when sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system does keep a more accurate datetime for the modified date, but Microsoft has removed the display of seconds from File Explorer, and they have disabled the ability to add extensions to File Explorer to enable this.

The short answer is that you can download other file management software that will display this, but File Manager is useless in this regard.